# How to check the result of a function

Tags: python, function

I have three functions
I want to check if the port is open and if it is open, perform function number two, otherwise perform function number three. I wrote the following code but it doesn't work

```
def port():
    a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    location = (ip, 80)
    check = a_socket.connect_ex(location)
    a_socket.close()


if port() == 0:
    other_function2()
else:
    other_function3()
```

Comment: `port()` doesn't return anything, so comparing the result with `0` makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something from the port() function. It is not returning anything right now. Use a return statement to return a value and then you can use the if statement with that value.

Comment: Thx, it all worked out